# Optics Spatial Resolution

Tags: optics

what does it mean to have a micrometer spatial resolution. Does it mean the resolution is 1 micrometer or can be 2,3,4,.... etc.?
I do not understand it. Is there anybody?

Comment: Resolution means that one can distinguish two lengths differing by 1um from each other. It does not mean, however, that the result is accurate to 1um.

Comment: Nor that it is precise to 1um.

Answer (score 1):

As ACuriousOne commented, if the smallest gradation on a ruler or other measurement device that you can observe is $1 \mu $ that's one definition.
In my world of optics and imaging,  there are similar definitions.  For example, if you have two imaged spots of light separated just enough to satisfy the [Rayleigh Criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_resolution) , their spatial separation is considered the resolution of your image.

Note that both this optical standard and the ability of a user to measure a length with a ruler are mildly subjective.  It's possible to determine that there are two spots even closer than the Rayleigh limit, because the image is not 'perfectly' round. For the ruler, some folks will place a limit of half the smallest unit inscribed on the ruler; others may claim a quarter of that unit, and so on.